# How to use static spring cloud stream url for launching spring cloud tasks?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-skipper

**Platform used** : Kubernetes.

I have an issue with Spring cloud stream url. I am launching my spring cloud tasks using spring cloud stream. Streams are deployed in kubernetes platform. Stream contains **http-kafka as source** and **taskLauncerKafka as sink**. I used **http-kafka kubernetes service url** to launch tasks. Kubernetes service url changes after each deployment which causes problem.The changes in the service name after each stream deployment is difficult to manage. I have tried enabling loadbalacer also. In that case also external ip-address changed after each stream roll-out.

I am using skipper for managing the deployments. Every time stream is deployed stream version changes which also changes stream url.

In my case , I have multiple instances from where I can launch spring-cloud task. If the stream url changes I need to make changes in the configmap of the deployment project for all instance and need to redeploy all instance.

Any solution ? I am thinking of centralised configuration management using **spring-cloud-config server or zookeeper**. In this case also I need to update the url. I can avoid deploying multiple instances using centralised configuration management.

**Skipper server version :** 2.4.1.RELEASE
**Dataflow server version :** 2.5.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of SCDF/Skipper you are running?
This looks similar to the issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-skipper/issues/953 which was subsequently addressed in Skipper 2.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the version of SCDF/Skipper. Let me go through the link you given. Ty

Comment: I have upgraded to latest stable version. Now its working fine. Thanks.